# Detect when fullscreen mode exited

Tags: javascript

I want to detect when fullscreen mode has been exited in chrome. So I have this code that is supposed to work correctly, But it dosn't...

```
// Detect if fullscreen is exited
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() { 

  console.log('fullscreen state changed');

  if(document.webkitIsFullScreen === false){
     console.log('Not in fullscreen');
  }

});
```

If I enter fullscreen mode via a button click the above code works fine, But when I enter to fullscreen mode using F11 or via chrome menu, it doesn't do anything! Why? And how to fix this...

Comment: seems issue with some particular browser, update and check in other version. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606177

Comment: There should be a trick to do it!

Comment: update version, and try

Comment: Updated still have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

There is one property and an event (as well as the equivalent on-event handler)  of the Fullscreen API that will facilitate OP's objective:

***Detect when fullscreen mode is exited***

### [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

1. Register `<html>` to the [`fullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Event_handlers_on_elements) event:

   ```
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', callbackFuction)

   /* OR */

   document.documentElement.onfullscreenchange = callbackFunction;
   ```
2. Determine if there's element in fullscreen mode using the [`.fullscreenElement`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%60.fullscreenElement%60) property:

   ```
   if (document.fullscreenElement) {...
   ```

---

#### Demo

**Note:** Fullscreen does not function properly on this site. Review this [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/nhkt3x8z/) to see the code function properly.

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
const main = document.querySelector('main');

root.onfullscreenchange = screenMode;
main.onclick = switchNode;

function switchNode(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  if (clicked.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    let selector = clicked.dataset.sel || ":root";
    const node = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (document.fullscreenElement && !clicked.classList.contains('full')) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
      clicked.classList.add('full');
      clicked.classList.remove('exit');
    } else {
      node.requestFullscreen();
      clicked.classList.add('exit');
      clicked.classList.remove('full');
    }
  }
}

function screenMode(event) {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
      button.classList.add('full');
      button.classList.remove('exit');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
:root,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 3vw/1.45 Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}

main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

figure {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 35vw;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/vYvt1Vx/bobafett2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
}

figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  background: transparent;
}

button.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

button.full {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

button.full::before,
button.exit::after {
  content: '\25c0';
}

button.full::after,
button.exit::before {
  content: '\25b6';
}

figure:fullscreen {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/7Qghbj3/bobafett1.jpg);
}

figure:-webkit-full-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button class='toggle full' type='button' style='float: right'></button>
  <figure class='frame'>
    <figcaption>
      <button class='toggle full' data-sel='.frame' type='button'></button>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</main>
```