# fullscreenchange event browser support

Tags: javascript, next.js, addeventlistener, fullscreen

I am trying to add an event listener for fullscreen change in my nextjs app and after looking around all the example codes I found use the webkit,moz and ms prefixes together.
And I wondering if we really need to use the 4 variants like this:

```
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
    document.addEventListener('msfullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
```

After testing on Edge, Chrome and Firefox it seems that it works just fine if I only use:
`document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange)`

So my question is: do I really need to use the other 3:

```
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
    document.addEventListener('msfullscreenchange', onFullScreenChange);
```

?

I also used this code from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fullscreenchange and the result was the same. It seems to work fine if I only use the fullscreenchange event .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myP {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open this page in fullscreen mode.</p>
<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Go Fullscreen Mode</button>
<button onclick="closeFullscreen();">Close Fullscreen</button>
<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.</p>
<p id="myP">I will display the event that was fired!</p>

<script>
/* Get the element you want displayed in fullscreen */ 
var elem = document.documentElement;

/* Function to open fullscreen mode */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem = window.top.document.body; //To break out of frame in IE
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

/* Function to close fullscreen mode */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    window.top.document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}

// Events
var output = document.getElementById("myP");
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() {
  output.innerHTML = "fullscreenchange event fired!";
});
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function() {
  output.innerHTML = "mozfullscreenchange event fired!";
});
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function() {
  output.innerHTML = "webkitfullscreenchange event fired!";
});
document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function() {
  output.innerHTML = "msfullscreenchange event fired!";
});
</script>

<p>Note: Internet Explorer 10 and earlier does not support fullscreen mode.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `w3schools` is bad, don't use it, please. See [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event#browser_compatibility)

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033185/detect-when-fullscreen-mode-exited)

Comment: Safari 16.3 seems to still need webkit prefix https://caniuse.com/fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

Maybe modern browsers now in days work fine with `fullscreenchange` event but you have to take in consideration that there are a lot of users with old computers/browsers and also other devices such as tablets, android, iPhones...

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a Tampermonkey script that detects when a video on a site changes to fullscreen. My experience with it now is that on some sites it is enough to work with fullscreenchange, while on other sites in my Chromium browser it only works with webkitfullscreenchange.

So it seems to depend not only on what the browser supports, but how a web video player switches to fullscreen mode.